# How to Reprocess old raw data from one table to another table?

Tags: java, sql-server

HI Am implementing one java application . The application will read data from the devices and store into database. Here my question is i have stored data only 1 month after that it will be deleted but i have backup in cd or writing it into files. suppose customer asked  3 months back data . How i reprocess that data using Sql server 2005. please give me idea how to do that..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you just want to create databases keeping only one month of history and glue them together in case you need that.
In this case you might do as follow:

```
CREATE DATABASE [TEST] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'TEST', FILENAME = X:\SOMEPLACE\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TEST.mdf' , SIZE = 2048KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON ( NAME = N'TEST_log', FILENAME = X:\SOMEPLACE\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TEST_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , FILEGROWTH =     10%)
GO
USE TEST
CREATE TABLE DATATBL (USRKEY INT IDENTITY(1,1), SOMEDATA VARCHAR(50))
/* IN A SQL SERVER AGENT SCRIPT YOU SCHEDULE TO RUN THE END OF THE MONTH*/
GO
DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @DBNAME ='TEST_HIST_' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '_' +CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
EXEC(
'CREATE DATABASE ['+@DBNAME+'] ON  PRIMARY ( NAME = N'''+@DBNAME+''', FILENAME =     N''X:\SOMEPLACE\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\'+@DBNAME+'.mdf'' , SIZE = 2048KB ,     FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )  LOG ON  ( NAME = N'''+@DBNAME+'_log'', FILENAME =     N''X:\SOMEPLACE\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\'+@DBNAME+'_log.ldf'' , SIZE = 1024KB ,     FILEGROWTH = 10%) ')
GO
DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(50)

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT @DBNAME ='TEST_HIST_' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '_' +CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2))
 EXEC('USE '+@DBNAME)
CREATE TABLE DATATBL (USRKEY INT , SOMEDATA VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO DATATBL SELECT * FROM TEST.DATATBL
DELETE FROM DATATBL

COMMIT TRANSACTION

/* ACCESSING DATA*/
GO
DECLARE @SCR VARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT * FROM TEST.DATATBL'
DECLARE @GETTOTMONTHS INT=3
DECLARE @CUR INT=0
DECLARE @CURDB VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @REFDATE DATE=DATEADD(MONTH,DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()),DATEADD(YEAR,DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()),0))
WHILE @CUR<@GETTOTMONTHS
BEGIN
    SET @REFDATE=DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@REFDATE)
    SET @CURDB = 'TEST_HIST_' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,@REFDATE) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '_' + CAST    (DATEPART(MONTH,@REFDATE) AS VARCHAR(2))
    IF @SCR>'' SET @SCR=@SCR+' UNION ALL '
    SET @SCR=@SCR+'SELECT * FROM '+@CURDB+'.DATATBL'
    SET @CUR=@CUR+1
END
SELECT @SCR
EXEC @SCR
```

I would not recommend dumping into a text file instead, ther would be obvious impact in terms of performance - after all, you can still detach/backup the mdf file which will be ready for reattach and reuse flawlessly